# Cannot resolve method setClient(okhttp3.OkHttpClient)

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I am using retrofit 1.9.0 and i have the following code.

```
private static String ROOT_URL = "www.mydomain.com";
public static RestAdapter restAdapter()
{
    OkHttpClient httpClient= new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();
    RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
    builder.setEndpoint(ROOT_URL);
    builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
    builder.setClient(httpClient);
    RestAdapter restAdapter = builder.build();
    return restAdapter;
}
```

but i get an error Cannot resolve method setClient(okhttp3.OkHttpClient). The error is not red in color but underlined with a red line. what might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the `setClient()` in *Retrofit 1.9* uses an `OkClient` and not `OkHttpClient` which is used in Retrofit 2.0. You can change the import to com.square.okhttp.OkHttpClient instead of okhttp3.OkHttpClient and use the corresponding methods. Something like the following

```
OkHttpClient httpClient= new OkHttpClient();
httpClient.setRetryOnConnectionFailure(true);
httpClient.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder();
builder.setClient(new OkClient(httpClient));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: After modifying the code as above i get the following error retryOnConnectionFailure has a private access in com.square.okhttp.okhttpclient